# gMSA for SQL 2014 and IIS 8.5

Tags: sql-server-2014, iis-8.5

Bart Van Keyenberg has a great [article](http://www.vankeyenberg.be/?p=1831) how to use gMSA (Group Managed Service Account) and why is it usefull.

Does anyone have experience with running SQL 2014 server cluster under gMSA (Group Managed Service Account), I've read there was a bug in SQL12. Will IIS AppPool, work after account password changes?